# Grails "loses" custom URL mapping when following any links on the page

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have an application where users can browse maps in two ways (like thumbnails and in a list)

```
/map/browse
/map/list
```

Now, I would like to restrict these views to just show maps of a specific user, for example through

```
/user/3/browse
/user/3/list
```

So I created the mapping:

```
"/user/$userId/browse" {
  controller = "map"
  action = "browse"
}

"/user/$userId/list" {
  controller = "map"
  action = "list"
}
```

Now, I can go to `/user/3/browse`, but as soon as I click on a pagination link or change the pagination filters, **the URL goes back to `/map/browse`**.

Also, if I set the `userId` to `null` in the controller, I get the error:

> Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : Unable to create URL for mapping [/user/(*)/list] and parameters [["action":"list", "controller":"map", "max":20, "offset":0, "sort":"uploadDate", "order":"desc", "userId":null, "totalMaps":30]]. Parameter [userId] is required, but was not specified! at /views/map/browse.gsp:26

The pagination works as follows:

```
<div class="paginateButtons">
    <g:paginate controller="map" action="browse" total="${mapInstanceTotal}"></g:paginate>
</div>
```

What can I do against that or what would be the correct way of implementing what I want?

<sub>I don't necessarily need to have that URL mapping, I only need a nice way of saying: "Display maps of only one user"</sub>

Comment: how you build your "pagination link"?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is not at your URL mapping configuration ,but in your way to create link. I think it's better if you use [Named URL Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings) : it's clearer than your approach now, and when create link for pagination you only need to specify the url name. For example:

In UrlMappings.groovy:

```
static mappings = {

    name accountDetails: "/details/$acctNumber" {
        controller = 'product'
        action = 'accountDetails'
    }
}
```

In view - gsp page:

```
<g:link mapping="accountDetails" params="[acctNumber:'8675309']">
    Show Account
</g:link>
```

Comment: I appreciate your example, but wouldn't it make more sense to rewrite it to the actual use case of mine (e.g. maps and users), because you probably know what you're talking about? :)

Comment: @slhck: I just found a quick example. Well, but if you use the paginate taglib then it's another story, since the taglib doesn't support named url mapping yet

Comment: Oh, that's bad. What would you suggest in that case? Can I just "carry" the user ID parameter with other pagination parameters?

Comment: @slhck: I often self-create the link instead of using pagination taglib. But if you want to use it, try transfer the "userId" parameter into the tag by using `params`. Please refer to: http://grails.org/GSP+Tag+-+paginate