# Map two levels and a variable to a controller

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I want to add the following to UrlMappings.groovy:

`"/level1/level2/$paramVariable"(controller:"doSomething", action: "index")`

For some reason, this mapping does not actually map the URL to the DoSomethingController. Is there a workaround other than turning level2 into a variable?

Comment: How does the URL look like which you are hitting?

Comment: createLink(controller: "doSomething", action: "paramVariableValue") makes a link "/doSomething/paramVariableValue", which leads to a 404 error page. Actually, when I enter in "/level1/level2/paramVariableValue" directly into the address bar, it works correctly. I guess my question is now: how should I go about making the link?

Comment: It looks like I want to used a named url mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946909/grails-loses-custom-url-mapping-when-following-any-links-on-the-page. I'll explore it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating the link with `createLink(controller: "doSomething", action: "paramVariableValue")` when it should have been `createLink(controller: "doSomething", params:[paramVariable:"paramVariableValue"]`.